# pass option containing comma to configure script (Linux)

Tags: linux, autoconf, configure

I have a configure script where I need to pass an option that contains a comma. Now if it weren't for the comma I could put some "s around to make configure recognize the string as a whole:

```
 ./configure --with-arpack="-Wl,-rpath,/my/path -L/my/path -larpack"
```

But the commas are interpreted as option delimiters, so the script only recognizes -Wl as the handed over option:

```
=== With linker flags: -Wl -rpath /my/path -L/my/path -larpack
```

How can I get around this?

Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

Use LDFLAGS and LIBS instead:

```
$ export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/my/path -L/my/path"
$ export LIBS="-larpack"
$ ./configure --with-arpack
```

Comment: +1, but it is more typical to pass the assignments as arguments to configure.  That is: './configure LDFLAGS="-Wl..."'